# JSON Parse in JAVA android

Tags: java, android, json

I need help parsing this json object.  My current Java code isn't parsing what I want, it's only parsing the cooking time:

```
"cooking_time_min":"15",
"directions":{  
  "direction":[  
     {  
        "direction_description":"Preheat oven to 390 °F (200 °C).",
        "direction_number":"1"
     },
     {  
        "direction_description":"Mix together minced lemon rind, lemon juice, chopped parsley, salt and cayenne.",
        "direction_number":"2"
     },
     {  
        "direction_description":"Rub snapper filets generously with mixture and place in baking dish.",
        "direction_number":"3"
     },
     {  
        "direction_description":"Place fish in oven and bake for about 10-15 minutes.",
        "direction_number":"4"
     }
  ]
 },
```

This is my Java code:

```
JSONObject recipe = new JSONObject(buffer.toString());
String cooking_time = recipe.getString("cooking_time_min");
Log.d("cooking_time", cooking_time);
JSONObject directions =    recipe.getJSONObject("directions");
JSONObject direction = directions.getJSONObject("direction");
String direction_description = direction.getString("direction_description");
Log.d("desc", direction_description);
JSONObject Ingredients = recipe.getJSONObject("ingredients");
JSONObject ingredient =   Ingredients.getJSONObject("ingredient");
```

Desired Output:

```
buffer.tostring is = E/Buffer: {"cooking_time_min":"15","directions":{"direction":[{"direction_description":"Preheat oven to 390 °F (2 ...
```

but all I am getting in my log is the cooking time and not the description.

Answer (score 0):

I formatted the JSON:

```js
{
  "recipe": {
    "cooking_time_min": "15",
    "directions": {
      "direction": {
        "direction_description": "Preheat oven to 390 °F (200 °C).",
        "direction_number": "1"
      }
    },
    "ingredients": {
      "ingredient": {
        "food_id": "38065",
        "food_name": "Snapper (Fish) (Mixed Species)",
        "ingredient_description": "1 1\/2 lbs snapper fillets",
        "ingredient_url": "http:\/\/www.fatsecret.com\/calories-nutrition\/usda\/snapper-(fish)-(mixed-species)?portionid=47968&portionamount=1.500",
        "measurement_description": "lb",
        "number_of_units": "1.500",
        "serving_id": "47968"
      }
    },
    "number_of_servings": "4",
    "preparation_time_min": "5",
    "rating": "4",
    "recipe_categories": {
      "recipe_category": {
        "recipe_category_name": "Seafood",
        "recipe_category_url": "http:\/\/www.fatsecret.com\/recipes\/collections\/ingredients\/seafood\/Default.aspx"
      }
    },
    "recipe_description": "Healthy fish with a tasty sauce.",
    "recipe_id": "91",
    "recipe_images": {
      "recipe_image": "http:\/\/www.fatsecret.com\/static\/recipe\/bf0c5912-9cf8-4e7a-b07a-6703c4b77082.jpg"
    },
    "recipe_name": "Baked Lemon Snapper",
    "recipe_types": {
      "recipe_type": "Main Dish"
    },
    "recipe_url": "http:\/\/www.fatsecret.com\/recipes\/baked-lemon-snapper\/Default.aspx",
    "serving_sizes": {
      "serving": {
        "calcium": "6",
        "calories": "177",
        "carbohydrate": "2.23",
        "cholesterol": "63",
        "fat": "2.32",
        "fiber": "0.6",
        "iron": "3",
        "monounsaturated_fat": "0.436",
        "polyunsaturated_fat": "0.788",
        "potassium": "752",
        "protein": "35.10",
        "saturated_fat": "0.490",
        "serving_size": "1 serving",
        "sodium": "692",
        "sugar": "0.58",
        "trans_fat": "0",
        "vitamin_a": "8",
        "vitamin_c": "32"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now it is obvious, that `recipe` is the first and single child of the root.
This code reads the json:

```
JSONObject foodGet = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
```

And you told us, that "it's only parsing the cooking time" (`cooking_time`):

```
String cooking_time = foodGet.getString("cooking_time_min");
```

If you get the cooking time, then you are not parsing this json file, because the root object has no child `cooking_time_min`.

I assume, that `foodGet` references the child `recipe`.

Try this:

```
JSONObject recipe = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
String cooking_time = recipe.getString("cooking_time_min");
JSONObject directions =    recipe.getJSONObject("directions");
JSONObject direction = directions.getJSONObject("direction");
String direction_description = direction.getString("direction_description");
JSONObject Ingredients = recipe.getJSONObject("ingredients");
JSONObject ingredient =   Ingredients.getJSONObject("ingredient");
...
```

Comment: that is correct, and because of that food.Get.getString gets the cooking time, but now I need to get another child and its not working

Comment: @Evan coding ok, you got the point? Your code cannot parse the child recipe (`foodGet.getJSONObject("recipe");`) because it does not exist in the object `foodGet` (or in the json-string `builder.toString()`)

Comment: so I should just declare it there and then I will be able to? or what

Comment: Ok, so I tried this... and im still not getting any other values. I have editted above to show you the new problem. i guess

Comment: `"direction":[{"direction_description"` it is not the JSON as shown in the question... It seems that `direction` is an array, so you have to use `JSONArray direction = directions.getJSONArray("direction");` I would analyze the JSON you get from the server. Try to put it in a JSON-Formatter (maybe your IDE)...

Comment: The api vs the server jesus .... totally different which is why Ive been having problems

Comment: ah ok - no documentation is better than a bad one ;) good luck.

Comment: I now have updated the json, in a formatted way If you can just give me an example I will be on my way on doing this. I am new to this :) Thx it is updated above

Comment: it is not so hard, see http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ and look for `JSONArray`